# How can I use pagination outside the SwiperJS container?

Tags: swiper.js

How can I use pagination outside the swiper-container class?
I using Swiper.js and pagination feature.
[Red area: Draggable area, but I need this area not dragable.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bvotw.png)

[My problem in gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyZS1.gif)

**How can I move the pagination from the draggable area to the non-draggable area?**

My Codes:

HTML/PHP

```
      <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <?php while ($posts_args->have_posts()) : $posts_args->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
              <?php get_template_part('template-parts/cards/card', 'article'); ?>
            </div>
          <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
      </div>
```

Javascript:

```
var Slider = (function() {
  var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    slidesPerView: 1,
    spaceBetween: 10,
    grabCursor: true,
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
      clickable: true,
    },
    breakpoints: {
      0: {
        slidesPerView: 1,
        spaceBetween: 10,
      },
      992: {
        slidesPerView: 2,
        spaceBetween: 15,
      },
      1200: {
        slidesPerView: 3,
        spaceBetween: 20,
      }
    }
  });
})();
```

Comment: Did you figure out how to style the pagination bullets?